# String index out of range when converting to argparse

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I changed from optparse to argparse but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
    if not option_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

My code is:

```
usage = "%prog -f <fasta TFs> -a <database all> -s <database small> -d <pfam database> [options]"
version = "1.0.1"
description = " "
epilog = " "\
         " "
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(usage=usage, description=description,
                      version="%prog "+version, epilog=epilog)

# options for running the program
# TF file
parser.add_argument("-f", "",  dest="TF", metavar="<file>",
                        help="input file with transcription factors")
parser.set_defaults(fasta=None)
```

I can't find where this error comes from, how can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get this error is by asking for an index that doesn't exist -- in this case, `option_string` must be empty.

Comment: Indeed - and the "empty" string for "option_string" comes from the empty string following "-f" in the add_argument call. Check argparse documentation on how to make adding "-f" on the command line optional

Answer (score 3):

In argparse you can't pass empty argument strings to add_argument. argparse is trying to find a valid prefix_char (e.g. "-" or "--") in the empty string you pass (""), causing the error. Try this instead:

```
parser.add_argument("-f",  dest="TF", metavar="<file>",
                    help="input file with transcription factors")
```